Protocol of MEMS digital microphone, and if microcontroller can detect it is missing
I have a datasheet for a MEMS microphone.
The way I interpret it, you have to tie L/R low to get DATA1, high to get DATA2. From another source, I guess that it's basically made to be use in a pair.
I get that you just provide the clock, and every 2nd cycle, you'll get some data.
I want to get rid of this microphone, but ideally without damaging the device. The device has only one microphone.
My interpretation is if I remove that component and tie "DATA" to GND, the microcontroller should always get a low signal, which is equivalent to an impressively quiet place.
The alternative being to not tie it, in which case the microcontroller may detect something is fishy because it should get a low value every 2nd cycle. If left floating, it may be read as high or low values.
Does that sound correct?

Why do you want to get rid of the microphone?

Privacy. Not a fan of connected microphones.

You need not include "help understanding..." in the title; that is implied simply by asking.

A viable replacement might be a 74LVC1G74 (or 2G; or 7SZ or TC7WZ families, etc.), wired as a type-T flip-flop so that the output alternates every clock cycle.  This is equivalent to a perfect (noise-free, as you surmise) sigma-delta modulation, for both channels (regardless of how or when they assign the L/R signal).
Such a chip can likely fit in the same footprint, or nearby space (what little space might be available in the device), of course this will require significant finesse to solder in, but as microelectronics work is concerned, it's doable.
Simply tying the line high or low, may work, but whether the MCU will report this as an error, only you can know -- you might test it and see.  I don't see that any harm can come of testing this, as long as ESD protections are followed, and you don't, like, accidentally short out the supplies or something.  (It could even be done with the device in circuit, if you don't mind momentarily shorting the microphone; while this is not a recommended operating condition, it's rare that it results in actual damage.  I guess since you're thinking of removing it anyway, the risk of damage is inconsequential.)
I will note that it is common for S-D devices to carve out the operating extremes: this is partly because S-D modulation doesn't work very well at such extremes to begin with (a <10% or >90% pulse stream is losing significant noise-bandwidth range due to having to spend so much time high or low by default), and some use a 0% or 100% (or close to it) level to indicate various kinds of malfunction.  But it is obviously unknowable from here, whether this applies to your case.
There may be other extenuating circumstances, like if this is a video recorder you just want muted, it may simply work 100% fine with a fixed input level, but neglects to remove DC from the output and encodes the ± full scale signal into the output verbatim; this may lead to unpleasant clicks during playback, distortion after mixing with other sources, or perhaps even incorrect operation of some playback devices (that aren't expecting DC in program matter).  Using the flip-flop avoids this scenario.

Thanks! Readig sigma delta in your answer, I went over the datasheet again and found where it's referred, which I had missed!

Not correct, the output is PDM so a long  strings of zero bits means very high negative differential pressure and a long string of one bits means very high positivr differential pressure.
In general these may be limited that a valid bitstream can never contain more that say 60 ones or zeroes out of 64 bits so having a signal tied low or high will be detected as invalid.
A true ideal silence will be on average a 50% zero bits and 50% one bits, an artificially generated PDM silence is thus an alternating stream of ones and zeroes. However, it may be unlikely to occur for very long in real world, so obviously, it can also be detected if the mic is replaced with a flip-flop that generates a perfect constant stream of 01010101 etc.
